# R Remove duplicates only for one group

Tags: r, duplicates

I looked through duplicates answers but couldn't find similar case to this. I want to remove duplicates only for one group and keep rest as it is. Can this be achieved with out creating temporary table?

Example:

I want to remove duplicates only for ID == "B", I don't care if there are duplicates in other IDs.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- tibble(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
       VAL = rep(1:3, 3),
       VAL2 = rep(1:3, 3)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

What I normally use to find duplicates in two columns.

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct(VAL, VAL2, .keep_all = T)
```

This will ofcourse find all duplicates, I can use filter and create a new table and then work from there, but looking way to remove ID == "B" duplicates and not touch other IDs. Can this be achieve without creating temp table?

My current workflow

```
B <- dt %>% 
  filter(ID == "B") %>% 
  distinct(VAL, VAL2, .keep_all = T)


dt %>% 
  filter(ID != "B") %>% 
  bind_rows(B)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  ID      VAL  VAL2
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 A         1     1
2 A         1     1
3 A         1     1
4 C         3     3
5 C         3     3
6 C         3     3
7 B         2     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly can be done similarly as you already did:

```
dt %>% 
  filter(ID == "B") %>% 
  distinct(VAL, VAL2, .keep_all = T) %>%
  bind_rows(dt %>% filter(ID != "B"))
```

It can also be achieved by using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[ID != "B" | !duplicated(dt, by=c("ID", "VAL", "VAL2"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative subsetting asking for duplicated for `ID=="B"`.

```
i <- which(dt$ID == "B")
dt[-i[duplicated(dt[i,])],]
#dt[-i[duplicated(dt[i,c("VAL", "VAL2")])],] #Alternative limiting to VAL and VAL2
#  ID      VAL  VAL2
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 A         1     1
#2 A         1     1
#3 A         1     1
#4 B         2     2
#5 C         3     3
#6 C         3     3
#7 C         3     3
```

Or you can use `rbind` after sub-setting `dt` and using `unique` on the selected rows.

```
i <- dt$ID == "B"
rbind(dt[!i,], unique(dt[i,]))
#  ID      VAL  VAL2
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 A         1     1
#2 A         1     1
#3 A         1     1
#4 C         3     3
#5 C         3     3
#6 C         3     3
#7 B         2     2
```

Comment: aah, my bad at formating question. These are not my only fields and there is multiple others, so I need unique by exactly these two fields. Apologies. I will reformat question.

Comment: Maybe `i <- which(dt$ID == "B"); dt[-i[duplicated(dt[i,c("VAL", "VAL2")])],]` comes to what you wanted?